# Which container should I use to quickly find an element, knowing that by construction it's already ordered?

Tags: c++, vector, find, set, containers

I have to use a container that by construction is already ordered and I need a quick find-function.

My idea is to use a set to exploit its `set.find`, which should be quick enough, but constructing my set with `set.insert` could be slow because I already know that the elements are ordered!

For this part, I could just use a vector with `vector.push_back`, but then I should write the find function myself and it would also be slower than the `set::find`... What do you suggest me?

EDIT:

- The container needs to be modified, but will always be ordered, and its size will always be the same (but i don't know it a priori)
- No repeated values.
- A lot more finds than inserts.
- I just need to know if it exists, not its position.
- I found the std::binary_search. Is it good?

Comment: Use lower_bound or upper_bound functions on vector (binary search). If you want to modify, use set or map.

Comment: I second SashaMNs suggestion.  In addition, as you probably know the number of entries, you can avoid unnecessary resizing by creating it with an appropriate capacity, using 'reserve'.

Comment: How frequent are the inserts vs finds?

Comment: @wewe, you are saying that the size of the container will be the same but you seem to imply that there will be inserts too after initialisation. What do you mean? If there are no inserts then I would use std::array, if there are a few inserts then std::set or std::unordered_set if there is a good hash function. std::binary_search is optimal on the std::array.

Answer (score 2):

Constructing a `set` from a pair of iterators is guaranteed to be O(N) if the input range is already sorted, so you could just use that. (See e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set.)

Subsequent inserts are O(log N).

Although if the total size is not that large a sorted `vector` tends to beat everything else because it is so cache friendly. `std::binary_search` is O(log N), the same as `set::find`.

`std::unordered_set` doesn't care about your ordering, but does give you O(1) lookup (on average, no guarantees).

Comment: Wouldn't a hashtable beat set since you get constant access time. OP does not want ordering it seems, no mention of iterating over the values in sorted order.

Comment: @SelçukCihan Yes - see the edit where I added a mention of `unordered_set`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` with `std::make_heap()`, `push_heap()`, `pop_heap()` and `sort_heap()` could help you to deal with it as fast as `std::set`. However, you'll need to use std::binary_search manually.